# Starting (inrush) current of a resistor (heater)

Tags: resistors, inrush-current, contactor

We are going to purchase a 48kW electric drying oven.

As we know the AC motors have big starting current and a special starting equipment is needed - Star-delta, soft-starter, inverter and etc.

What is the situation with the simple resistors/heaters?

Is there a need for a special starting equipment? Or we can just connect them Direct-on-line. 16kW to each phase with a contactors?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hmm, if you need to ask this then I would strongly suggest to hire an expert for this. Someone with **experience** in this field. Do it wrong (how do you know the advice given here is good for your particular situation?) and things can blow up. Still, your choice but I know what I would do. Also: what does the datasheet say?

Comment: More than strongly recommend an expert in your case

Comment: How the oven's heater is going to work? Is it going to swich on/off  during the industrial process (thermostat by)? or it will be on throughout the process?

Comment: Do you have details on the oven? It will have some control electronics. Also multiple elements and fans.

Comment: Yes, the heater is going to switch on/of during the process.

The contactors will be controlled by a PLC

Comment: To add to the other cautions, this the domain of your local Electrical Code. Calculate all you want, but actually build it to Code and manufacturers drawings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resistors/heaters are not simple.

The inrush to a heater depends on how hot it gets, and the temperature coefficient of the material.

For a resistor with a nominally zero tempco, so component resistors, or resistors made from specialist resistance alloys, there will be essentially no inrush.

For a filament lamp, the resistor runs hot, and the tungsten filament has a strong tempco. You can expect an inrush of up to 10x running current when they are first turned on.

There are other heater types between these two extremes. Single metals will tend to have a small tempco in the 0.5% to 1% per degree region, which will result in a tiny inrush, probably much less than 2x. Quartz tube radiant heaters do not run quite as hot as filament light bulbs, and tend to use an alloy rather than tungsten, so could be anywhere in the none to 10x inrush range.

You have to find out, for your proposed heaters, how hot the heater wire itself is going to run, and what material it's made from. Or just measure the inrush.

Comment: And its thermal time constant - whether it takes 10 ms or an hour to reach temperature.

Comment: ... will alter the duration of the inrush pulse